# parse content between anchors recursively

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, text-parsing, python-re

I have text file like below (have uneven formatting) but recursive words at start and end.

```
BIOGRF 
HETATM 1 Mo 40.08445 40.01794 39.96045 Mo 0 
0 0.00000 
HETATM 2 S 40.11010 39.74130 42.52913 S 0 
0 0.00000 
HETATM 3 S 41.90615 40.11835 41.77870 S 0 
0 0.00000 
HETATM 4 S 38.24215 41.79805 39.59043 S 0 
0 0.00000 
HETATM 5 S 39.98030 42.28845 38.74011 S 0 
0 0.00000 
HETATM 6 S 38.87623 37.84835 39.19281 S 0 
0 0.00000 
HETATM 7 S 40.63247 38.15194 38.28732 S 0 
0 0.00000 
FORMAT CONECT (a6,12i6) 
CONECT 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
CONECT 2 1 3 
CONECT 3 1 2 
CONECT 4 1 5 
CONECT 5 1 4 
CONECT 6 1 7 
CONECT 7 1 6 
UNIT ENERGY kcal 
ENERGY -565.964445 
END 
BIOGRF 
{........}
END
BIOGRF 
{........}
END
```

Whats the best way to extract the content between BIOGRF and END recursively? Is it possible to process in parallel in python?
Also is there way to create dict so can store content between BIOGRF and END?

I have tried

```
#import re
f = open('pdf/plain_text_mos.txt')
test_str = f.read()

regex = r"BIOGRF(.*?)"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
   print(matchNum, match)
```

OUPUT

```
1 <re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='BIOGRF'>
2 <re.Match object; span=(698, 704), match='BIOGRF'>
3 <re.Match object; span=(1401, 1407), match='BIOGRF'>
4 <re.Match object; span=(2026, 2032), match='BIOGRF'>
5 <re.Match object; span=(2717, 2723), match='BIOGRF'>
6 <re.Match object; span=(3403, 3409), match='BIOGRF'>
7 <re.Match object; span=(4093, 4099), match='BIOGRF'>
8 <re.Match object; span=(4716, 4722), match='BIOGRF'>
9 <re.Match object; span=(5540, 5546), match='BIOGRF'>
10 <re.Match object; span=(6366, 6372), match='BIOGRF'>
```

Comment: I would not overthink it. I'll just iterate per line and check if line contains `BIOGRF` or `END` to signal start and end.

Comment: Why do you want to do it recursively? Why are you unsatisfied with the non-recursive solution you've already got?